# Can I make two payments at the same time silently

Tags: paypal

I have integrated the paypal ios sdk and I want to know that if I can silently make two payments from the total amount that the user paid. My scenario is that when a user pays for something I want that amount to be credited in two accounts. I have searched but could not find anything related to this.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm a little confused.  Are you trying to split the payment between two accounts?  So if it's $100 you want $50 going to one account and $50 going to another, or what exactly?

Comment: Yes that is what exactly i am looking for in the mobile sdk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look into Adaptive Payments.  Specifically Parallel and Chained payments.